# What is the SHA-1 Signature used for in modules?

Tags: module

I've noticed when I go to download modules from some extension providers that they include the SHA-1 Signature, for example

> Module Example v1.2.1
>
> File size: 34.18 Kb 
>   SHA1 Signature: c7a8ffa0503bb59320ef40c1f559e4fa36fb2092
>   Compatibility: Joomla 3.0 
>   |Download now| |Direct Link|

What is the 'SHA1 Signature' - how is it used by the extension developers and/or the Joomla! CMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number is a hash value or a **Checksum**.

A hash value processed on the downloaded file is a way to make sure that the content is transferred OK and has not been damaged during the download process.

**What is SHA?**

> SHA stands for "secure hash algorithm". The four SHA algorithms are
>   structured differently and are named SHA-0, SHA-1, SHA-2, and SHA-3.
>   SHA-0 is the original version of the 160-bit hash function published
>   in 1993 under the name "SHA": it was not adopted by many applications.
>   Published in 1995, SHA-1 is very similar to SHA-0, but alters the
>   original SHA hash specification to correct alleged weaknesses. SHA-2,
>   published in 2001, is significantly different from the SHA-1 hash
>   function.

<sup>([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1))</sup>

Basically, it's a "fingerprint" or a *checksum* of the file, and the purpose is to allow a user to make sure the original, unaltered file has been downloaded. This helps avoid corrupt downloads, and files modified by third parties. There are many algorithms to generate a checksum, and SHA1 is only one of them (MD5 is another common variant).

A unique number (often called checksum) is generated based on the file contents. The end user can pass the downloaded file through a program to get the checksum, and if the file is identical to the original file, the checksum will also be the same. Even the smallest change to the file will give a different checksum. Note that different algorithms will produce different checksums, you can't compare a MD5 checksum or a SHA2 checksum with a SHA1 checksum.

**Resources**

- [SHA1 on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1)
- [Checksum on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum)

Answer (score 0):

SHA-1 is now, insecure. Not recommended in 2022.

Comment: This answer has been auto-flagged by the system as low-quality due to its length. I would like to note as well that this answer does not attempt to answer: "_What is the 'SHA1 Signature' - how is it used by the extension developers and/or the Joomla! CMS?_" You can very easily post your correct insight as a comment under the question or [edit] your answer to better address the specific question asked.  Relevant insights are good and important, but all answers must attempt to answer the asked question.  Thank you for contributing.